# How to import and use system gpg keys without subprocess

Tags: python, gnupg

I have decided to look back into how a script of mine pulls in a gpg key and encrypts passwords with that key. Currently, I am using subprocess to run the commands on the host like so:

```py
def check_for_imported_gpg_key():
    gpg_keys = subprocess.check_output(["gpg", "-k"]).decode("utf-8")
    if "pillar" in gpg_keys:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def encrypt_pillar_password(password):
    hashed_pass = crypt.crypt(str(password))
    key_imported = check_for_imported_gpg_key()
    if key_imported is False:
        print("OI! Import the key bud!")
    print("Encrypting Password with Pub Key")
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        (
            "gpg",
            "--armor",
            "--batch",
            "--trust-model",
            "always",
            "--encrypt",
            "-r",
            "pillar",
        ),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    gpg_message = process.communicate(input=hashed_pass.encode())[0]
    if "BEGIN PGP MESSAGE" in str(gpg_message):
        return gpg_message
    else:
        print("Something went wrong when generating the encrypted hash")
        print(str(gpg_message))
        return None
```

Is there a better, more pythonic way of completing this task? I am not currently aware of any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

So far, other than manually applying cryptographic primitives to messages (not recommended), spawning a subprocess is the best way to access gnupg in python. There is a third-party module called `python-gnupg`, but it is mainly a wrapper for the gpg binary.

Comment: That is also all I have found, I am sure the library would help my code look more pythonic but it would not in any way improve on the security when I am doing essentially the same thing as the library.

Comment: If your purpose is _security_, both gpg and python-gnupg in particular are poorly-chosen tools for the job (and I say this as a contributor to python-gnupg). The Go `x/crypto/openpgp` library is such a better implementation it's outright night-and-day. I simply do not use Python for code that needs to parse or generate OpenPGP messages anymore, and do not recommend that others do so either.

Comment: ...if you read through the python-gnupg code, you'll see it trying to adapt to different streams of event messages being expected/normal/anticipated for different versions of gpg on the backend -- with an understanding that it's unsafe to just ignore an unrecognized message, because that message might mean something critical (f/e, that we didn't find an integrity packet on the end of the input file whose output we just emitted).